# Random Uniform Distribution

Tags: java, random

So i want to get random elements of a list with uniform distribution in Java. I know that in the [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class, for example the nextInt method, already give me something like that:

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

So given something like the code below:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int numTimes = 10;
for(int i = 0; i < numTimes*n; i++){
   System.out.println(rnd.nextInt(10));
}
```

I expect that for small "n" I can't quite see a good uniform distribution, probably increasing it, I will see something better. So my question is, how can I guarantee a uniform distribution within smaller n, or in other words, with "n = 2" how can I get every number at least once?

---

Trying to explain better: giving 10-number range dataset, and for example 20 iterations, is there a way that each number is printed 1-3 times, in other words, at least once?

Comment: If you're guaranteeing it, then it's not random anymore...

Comment: In a (discrete) uniform distribution, each value has an equal **chance** of occurring. It doesn't mean that each value occurs an equal number of time. There's nothing wrong with your code for small "n".

Comment: Do you want it to be uniformly random, or do you want to see each number an equal number of times?

Comment: I agree with you, maybe I was just dreaming with something like "randomly get all the files from a list with a fixed number of iterations". It's possible to check if the position was already accessed somehow to guarantee it somehow, but it'll be very inefficient, I think. I was hoping to see some directions if my benchmark can work the way that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate numbers that occur exactly the same number of times (which is not the same as a uniform distribution), then there is a better way to do it.

```
int n = 2; // your "n"
int t = 100; // how often you want each number x to occur, where 0 <= x < n

// Build a list of numbers
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        l.add(j);
    }
}
// Shuffle the list randomly; this ensures the order is random but each number x occurs
// as often as any other x
Collections.shuffle(l);

for (Integer value : l) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

If you want to have some numbers at least once, but don't care about the others; then insert 1 of each number that you want at least once and the rest randomly. If I understand you correctly, you want the numbers 1, 2 and 3 at least once, and then randomly numbers 1, 2 and 3. So, that would be:

```
int n = 3; // your "n"

// Build a list of numbers
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
for (int x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
     l.add(x);
}

int t = 17; // add 17 more random numbers in range 1-3 inclusive

for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
    l.add(rnd.nextInt(n) + 1);
}

// Shuffle
Collections.shuffle(l);

// Print
for (Integer value : l) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: Changing the for loop strategy, it almost look like what I am expecting. Considering "t = 10", doing the way that you did, I will randomly get numbers from the range [0-9] twice, is gonna be guarantee indeed. But I was hoping something like, given like 20 iterations that each number were accessed 1-3, but at least once.

Comment: If t = 10, and n = 2, you get 10 times the numbers 0 and 1.

Comment: ok, you manage to get the result that I was expecting with a nice workaround. But I don't think this is gonna be give me a better performance and like you said "In a (discrete) uniform distribution, each value has an equal chance of occurring. It doesn't mean that each value occurs an equal number of time", I just can't guarantee it.